# android how to register an app for "open with" selection

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-manifest, android-usb

When connecting an external device(e.g. camera) via usb to a android smartphone you usually get a pop-up: "Choose an app for the USB device" with some different applications in the select box.

So my simple question is: how can i get my own app inside the selection.

Everything I could find on stackoverflow are filter-intents, but i'm not even sure if this is the right direction as they are mainly used for file opening and stuff like that.

Thanks to the comments i came up with this:

```
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
        </activity>
```

If i got it right (apparently I don't) with this setup the application should now be visible in the selection when attaching a usb device, but it still isn't.

Edit:
Solution:
I had to add: `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.accessory" />`
and

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" android:resource="@xml/usb_device_filter" />
```

while stting at least `protocol="0"` in the filter.

Comment: `intent-filter` is the way to do. They are used for file handling, but also for lots and lots of other platform actions. You just have to figure out what is the correct `intent-filter` for the specific action you want your app to handle.

Comment: here, that's how you do it: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html create the intent filter for `USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED` and an extra meta-data to filter the type of USB device to be a camera.

Comment: Thanks for this guidance but do I need to set it specific for cameras? I would like to allow this app to be opened with every external device. I may be work-blind right now, but is there some explanation for the "usb-device" attributes?

Comment: I never worked with those. I have no idea. I believe you must put some type of boundary or else your app will be called for mouse, game controllers webcam, anything. You want to at least be `Mass Storage` devices.